# importação do ROOT-cern dentro de uma virtual env e dentro da lxplus

Tags: pandas, tensorflow, virtualenv

Eu preciso utilizar o CondorHT(software do CERN) para minha analise , porem o macro de python que quero que ele trabalhe tem umas bibliotecas que não podem ser importadas na lxplus(ambiente do cern), então criei ma maquina virtual e assim:

```
/work/f/fassunca/private/myenv

$source venv/bin/activate     
$(env) pip install pandas #ok    
$(env) pip install tensorflow # ok    
$(env) pip install ROOT #(ROOT-CERN)
```

Não é possível instalar !

De maneira redundante eu faço:

```
$(venv) python3.6 # atual versão da lxplus  
>>> import pandas    
>>> import tensorflow    
>>> import ROOT
error: No found ROOT (se não instalou, não poderia importar)
```

Agora fora da virtual env:

```
$(venv) deactivate

$python3.6
>>> import ROOT # ok
>>> import pandas ou tensorflow 
error: No found
```

Também tentei fazer via conda, então instalei o conda numa virtual *env* tentei instalar lo *ROOT*
Não foi possível , mas eu criei outra virtual *env* e instalei o *conda* , então mandei instalar o *ROOT* e deu certo, mas ai não pude instalar o pandas. Outra coisa , em meu terminal tenho *python3.8* e não tenho nenhum problema com esse macro, mesmo dentro de uma *virtualenv*.

Answer (score 0):

Na [documentação](https://root.cern/install/) de instalação do PyROOT, **NÃO** consta que o mesmo pode ser instalado via `pip install

Para instalação no conda, segundo a mesma documentação, faça:

```
$ conda create -c conda-forge --name <my-environment> root
$ conda activate <my-environment>
```

Comment: Olá Paulo, muito obrigado! Contudo não deu certo, já havia tentado!
Duas coisas:

1)Tentei a instalação via conda e deu certo, mas logo depois não conseguia instalar o pandas e se eu instalar o pandas na virtual env antes, então não consigo instalar via conda.

2) O pyROOT instala, mas não faz a importação do ROOT e de varias bibliotecas que eu uso.

Comment: Qual o SO vc está usando?